# Function of demultiplexers in Register File

Tags: digital-logic, multiplexer, cpu, register, logisim

What is the function of demultiplexers (DMX) in this Logisim diagram of a Register File design:

[image]

Also could you explain the meaning of:

dreg,sreg,treg

dsel,ssel,tsel

dwrite,swrite,twrite

Comment: DMUX is an "Enhanced decoder" such that given the selected line, the output of this line is the DMUX input(0 or 1) unlike the decoder which assures that its always 1

Why DMUX?
1-to select one of the registers
2-to be able to write data into this register by setting the DMUX input to a 0 or 1 [Enable]

Comment: @AbdoMohamed So can we say that the right half of diagram related with storing and left side related with loading?

Comment: @AbdoMohamed or the exact opposite?

Comment: @AbdoMohamed regval and DMXs are input right?

Comment: Exactly, i`m posting an answer if this is not clear enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First let me define a simple *Register*

[image]

**INPUTS**: **Write**,**Data_in[16]**,**CLK**

**OUTPUTS**: **Data_out[16]**

IF the **Write** pin is **HIGH**, the data in the **Data_in[16]** will be stored in this register the next clock cycle (Rising or falling edge)

The **Write** pin is connected to the **DMUX** outputs so you can choose one of the 8 registers to write by providing the proper select value[SEL pin] and a '1' on the **Dmux** input

So for example if i want to write data in **R5**

1- Put the data in **regval[16]**

Since **regval[16]** is connected to all the 8 registers, we need to select only one of the 8 registers to store this value

How can we make this !

By using a **DMUX**

[image]

2- I`ll set **dsel[ 3]** to '**101**' to make sure that the **DMUX** is selecting the 5th register

3- Then i`ll set **dwrite** to '1' to make sure that the 5th register '**Write**' pin is triggered **HIGH** and the data in **regval** will be stored only in this register the next clock cycle edge

Now we are able to Select one of the 8 registers and write the data only to it even though all the registers **Data_in[16]** pin are connected to the same bus (**regval**)

Same idea when reading

Connect all the registers **Data_out[16]** pin to the **Mux** inputs, then output only one of them by providing the proper value on the select (**sel**) pin

For example if i want to read the value of R5

[image]

1-I`ll put '**101**' on **dsel[ 3]**

2- read the register stored value from the **Mux** output

---

### Why **dsel**,**ssel**,**tsel**

when making an ALU operation for example adding two numbers and storing them in a register

R[d] = R[s] + R[t]

**D** is the **destination** register where the result is stored

**S** and **T** are the two **operands**